# How to get a particular line from a file

Tags: ruby, file-io

Is it possible to extract a particular line from a file knowing its line number? For example, just get the contents of line `N` as a string from file "text.txt"?

Comment: I felt really misleaded by a lot of answers below. IMHO, the best one is the comment below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015415/6320039): no memory issue, and straight to the point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try one of these two solutions:

```
file = File.open "file.txt"

#1 solution would eat a lot of RAM
p [*file][n-1]

#2 solution would not
n.times{ file.gets }
p $_

file.close
```

Comment: Is solution #2 getting line n+1?

Comment: @Mark Thomas, in #1 too. I supposed indexing from 0.

Comment: Thanks for `[*File.open('…')]`, did not know that `to_a` for File instance can give me its lines

Comment: @Nakilon: file lines are indexed from 1 (all editors and even `cat -n` do so)

Comment: Regarding #2: I think unsplat is costly operation. Also, syntax is confusing.

Answer (score 26):

You could get it by index from `readlines`.

```
line = IO.readlines("file.txt")[42]
```

Only use this if it's a small file.

Comment: This is only the right answer if the file is small, less than a couple MB. Otherwise it'll force Ruby to load the entire file at once, which, in the case of a large file is slower than using a `foreach` or `gets` based solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189262/why-is-slurping-a-file-bad which contains benchmarks.

Comment: I was surprised to learn that it takes as much as a couple of MB!

Answer (score 6):

```
def get_line_from_file(path, line)
  result = nil

  File.open(path, "r") do |f|
    while line > 0
      line -= 1
      result = f.gets
    end
  end

  return result
end

get_line_from_file("/tmp/foo.txt", 20)
```

This is a good solution because:

- You don't use `File.read`, thus you don't read the entire file into memory. Doing so could become a problem if the file is 20MB large and you read often enough so GC doesn't keep up.
- You only read from the file until the line you want. If your file has 1000 lines, getting line 20 will only read the 20 first lines into Ruby.

You can replace `gets` with `readline` if you want to raise an error (`EOFError`) instead of returning nil when passing an out-of-bounds line.

Comment: Hehe, that's what you get from fellow Rubyists when you try to write optimized code eh? :)

Comment: In different languages you must optimize different things.

Comment: I'd argue that reading an entire 20MB file into memory to get one line from it is bad practice in any language.

Comment: ..I'd also argue that `get_line_from_file` is a terrible method name.  And that the implementation itself could be rewritten to be more ruby-like. But I digress..

Comment: @August Lilleaas, i'd argue, that here you don't need `result = nil`, `return` and write C-style loops, when you have `times`.

Comment: It's a matter of preference. I prefer to explicitly have a return for longer methods where you're supposed to use the return value. I think it increases clarity by making the usage of the method clearer.

Comment: @August Lilleaas, I think, Ruby is not your language of life ..)

Comment: Thankfully, I can write as much ruby as I want, the way I want, and I don't have to listen to what cargo culters want me to do :)

Comment: @AugustLilleaas when you use a language, however, you _should_ write it idiomatically, if only for the reason that languages often optimize idiomatic constructs more than other ones. Also, if anyone's ever going to maintain your code, it's a disservice to not learn the right way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

File has a nice `lineno` method.

```
def get_line(filename, lineno)
  File.open(filename,'r') do |f|
     f.gets until f.lineno == lineno - 1
     f.gets
  end
end
```

Comment: You don't really need lineno(). You could replace the 'until' line with `(lineno-1).times {f.gets}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
linenumber=5
open("file").each_with_index{|line,ind|
  if  ind+1==linenumber
    save=line
    # break or exit if needed.
  end
}
```

or

```
linenumber=5
f=open("file")
while line=f.gets
  if $. == linenumber # $. is line number
    print "#{f.lineno} #{line}" # another way
    # break  # break or exit if needed
  end
end
f.close
```

If you just want to get the line and do nothing else, you can use this one liner

```
ruby -ne '(print $_ and exit) if $.==5' file
```

Comment: Nice. That's when global $-variables become useful.

Comment: This keeps on reading the file when the line is already found.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If the line number is last 2nd line for example, it has to read until that line as well...

Answer (score 0):

If you want one liner and do not care about memory usage, use (assuming lines are numbered from 1)

```
lineN = IO.readlines('text.txt')[n-1]
```

or

```
lineN = f.readlines[n-1]
```

if you already have file opened.

Otherwise it would be better to do like this:

```
lineN = File.open('text.txt') do |f|
          (n-1).times { f.gets } # skip lines preceeding line N
          f.gets                 # read line N contents
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

These solutions work if you want only one line from a file, or if you want multiple lines from a file small enough to be read repeatedly. Large files (for example, 10 million lines) take much longer to search for a specific line so it's better to get the necessary lines sequentially in a single read so the large file doesn't get read multiple times.

Create a large file:

```
File.open('foo', 'a') { |f| f.write((0..10_000_000).to_a.join("\n")) }
```

Pick which lines will be read from it and make sure they're sorted:

```
lines = [9_999_999, 3_333_333, 6_666_666].sort
```

Print out those lines:

```
File.open('foo') do |f|
  lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
    (line - (index.zero? ? 0 : lines[index - 1]) - 1).times { f.gets }
    puts f.gets
  end
end
```

This solution works for any number of lines, does not load the entire file into memory, reads as few lines as possible, and only reads the file one time.